# How to store a file save path

Tags: 20.04, files, directory, 21.10

I save a file in a folder.
At the next save (from a different file) I have to reset the entire path.
How can I memorize it in order to have the saves all in the first path until the end of the work section?

Comment: Each application does this differently.  You will have to add to your question more information, like what applications you want to do this in.